# How do I create array of data from Users table in Rails Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User table with the columns `full_name, email, phone, address, city, state, zip`

I need to create an array from the User table that contains the fullname and email in this format
["user1.full_name, user1.email", "user2.full_name, user2.email" etc]

I am having trouble writing this query.

This is what I have so far

```
#create empty arrays
full_names = []
emails = []
#populate the full_names array
user_full_name = User.all
user_full_name.each{|x| full_names<<x.full_name}
#populate the emails array
user_email = User.all
user_email.each{|x| emails<<x.email}

#combine the two arrays
full_names.zip(emails)
```

But that gives me a multidimensional array of
[["full_name, email"], ["full_name, email"] etc]

How do I get it in the format of
["full_name, email", "full_name, email" etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two<sup>*</sup> possible solutions and their corresponding SQL:

```rb
# SELECT "users"."full_name", "users"."email" FROM "users"
User.pluck('full_name', 'email').map{ |u| u.join(', ')}.flatten

# SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
User.all.map { |u| "#{u.full_name}, #{u.email}" }
```

So `pluck` is more efficient than `all.map` because it only selects the attributes  you want.

<sup>*</sup> Both of which were mentioned in an earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.all.map do |user|
  "#{user.full_name}, #{user.email}"
end
```

See [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

---

To give a little more info on this. When you use an [ActiveRecord::QueryMethod](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) (e.g. you make a query through ActiveRecord) the result is not actually an array, however it *behaves* like an array, and by calling an array method on it, you fetch the results (See [ActiveRecord::Relation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)). That was a mouthful, but hopefully the following examples will be clearer:

```
# This builds a query but doesn't actually fire it!
users = User.all

# chain onto the query - it still won't be fired yet
users = users.where.not(name: "Rick")

# see the query that will be run
users.to_sql

# check the type of this variable
users.class
# => ActiveRecord::Relation

# evaluates the query
users.count

# evaluates the query
users.to_a

# evaluates the query
users.any? { |user| user.email.nil? }

# evaluates the query
users.map { |user| user.full_name }

# evaluates the query
# does the same thing as the previous line
users.pluck(:first_name)
```